# Missing disk space

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, raid

I have a 2.4TB disc (Raid 1) and all I see is about 400GB.
(df -h output is pasted below)

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                94G     0   94G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               19G  2.6M   19G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  109G   67G   38G  65% /
tmpfs                               94G     0   94G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               94G     0   94G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  111M  799M  13% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  7.9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop1                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop2                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/loop3                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
tmpfs                               19G   80K   19G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop5                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop6                         100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10859
/dev/loop7                         157M  157M     0 100% /snap/code/59
```

Where is the rest of the space and how can I reclaim it?

The output of lsblk is:
fish404@nemtolia:~/miniconda3/envs$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop1                       7:1    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10707
loop2                       7:2    0  69.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19188
loop3                       7:3    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
loop4                       7:4    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop5                       7:5    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop6                       7:6    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/10859
loop7                       7:7    0 156.7M  1 loop /snap/code/59
loop8                       7:8    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/10908
sda                         8:0    0 223.5G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   222G  0 part
└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   111G  0 lvm  /

Thanks

Comment: It appears that you are using LVM for your root partition - is it possible that you have configured most of your disks physical space for the volumes, but nor partitioned it to become available?  Can you append your question with the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: You might find this helpful https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux in particular the section after Extending Volume Group. There is probably lots of space available, it’s just not been added to the volume group. Don’t overlook the filesystem resize step. Make sure you have a backup of any data you cannot afford to lose.

Answer (score 0):

`df` is only showing size of volumes mounted. The missing size will be on what is **NOT** mounted. For that you can use `lsblk` command instead:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL |egrep -v "^loop"

NAME         FSTYPE LABEL            MOUNTPOINT               SIZE MODEL
nvme0n1                                                       477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB               
├─nvme0n1p9  swap                    [SWAP]                   7.9G 
├─nvme0n1p7  ext4   Old_Ubuntu_16.04 /mnt/old                23.1G 
├─nvme0n1p5  ntfs                                             859M 
├─nvme0n1p3                                                    16M 
├─nvme0n1p1  ntfs                                             450M 
├─nvme0n1p8  ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux /mnt/e                     9G 
├─nvme0n1p10 ext4   Ubuntu_18.04     /mnt/clone              27.2G 
├─nvme0n1p6  ext4   New_Ubuntu_16.04 /                       45.1G 
├─nvme0n1p4  ntfs   NVMe_Win10       /mnt/c                 363.2G 
└─nvme0n1p2  vfat                    /boot/efi                 99M 
mmcblk0                                                     119.1G 
└─mmcblk0p1  vfat   SANDISK128       /media/rick/SANDISK128 119.1G 
sr0                                                          1024M DVD+/-RW DW316  
sda                                                         931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4       ntfs   WINRETOOLS                                450M 
├─sda2                                                        128M 
├─sda5       ntfs   Image                                    11.4G 
├─sda3       ntfs   HGST_Win10       /mnt/d                   919G 
└─sda1       vfat   ESP                                       500M
```

Note you can call `lsblk` with no parameters but the extra parameters used makes a nicer, shorter display.